# Compute average of a column, excpet for the first row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to compute some queries, with the aggregates functions.
The problem is I'm not able to compute the average of the column, without the first value.

**example**

```
_myColumn_
10
15
20
```

Final average: (10 + 15 + 20) / 3 = 15

**What I want is: (15 + 20) / 2 = 12.5**

This is the code I've tried without success

```
select avg(age) from testing
except
select avg(age) from testing
limit 1
```

Comment: How do you define "first value"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: This table really needs to have a SERIAL or a (unique) position column to sort on..  Otherwise no trustworthy SQL query is possible..  To add to @GordonLinoff 's comment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `OFFSET` clause to skip the first row. (You should really ensure the order with an `ORDER BY` clause.) Then compute the AVG on that result:

```
select avg(age)
from
(
    select age from testing
    offset 1
) dt
```

Or, if the *first row* is expected to be the one with the lowest age:

```
select (sum(age) - min(age)) / (count(*) - 1)
from testing
```

Comment: The use of `OFFSET` without `ORDER BY` is non-sensical.  It does not answer the question.  It removes an *arbitrary* row; not anything considered "first".

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "first" row in SQL, because tables represent *unordered* sets.  A column is needed to specify the ordering.

Let me assume you mean the row with the smallest value.  This is a little tricky, but you can use `row_number()`:

```
select avg(age)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by age) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: I don't want to put any order by clause. The homework I have to do, is to compute the average, without the first value of the column, whatever that value may be.

Comment: your warning on the question also more or less also counts for this query..  if the topicstarter has equal values in the sort column the `order by` is still considerd non deterministic ("random") for those equal values.

Comment: *"I don't want to put any order by clause. "* @SHlMRJ you have to as SQL standards have defined SQL tables/resultset to be **always** orderless without `ORDER BY` ...

Comment: *"tell your teacher the exercise is senseless."* @klin maybe the point of the exercise is finding that out and modify the table stucture/data???

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose use something like this(some field Should be UNIQUE, for example ID if you have one)

```
SELECT AVG(age) FROM testing WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM testing ORDER BY ??SOMETHING HERE?? limit 1)
```

Comment: I don't want to put any order by clause. The homework I have to do, is to compute the average, without the first value of the column, whatever that value may be.

Comment: ok, remove order by. But selection will be "random". And you still need unique field. No other way as far as i know. Correction, my mistake @jarlh show OFFSET. I forgot it